# Multivariate time series with additional features

Tags: regression, time-series, bayesian, forecasting, hierarchical-bayesian

I am dealing with a problem that contains multiple categorical features and different time series depending on these variables. So, for example the dataset can be represented as:

| Day | catA | catB | catC | productA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | B | 1.8 |
| 2 | A | B | B | 2.4 |
| 3 | A | B | B | 2.8 |
| 4 | A | B | B | 3.8 |
| 5 | A | B | B | 4.4 |
| 6 | A | B | B | 4.8 |
| 7 | A | B | B | 5.4 |

...
...
With *n* days recorded.
The fact is that during this same time, in parallel, another product is being registered with some of the categorical features in common:

| Day | catA | catB | catC | productB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | 1.1 |
| 2 | A | B | C | 1.4 |
| 3 | A | B | C | 1.8 |
| 4 | A | B | C | 1.8 |
| 5 | A | B | C | 1.2 |
| 6 | A | B | C | 3.8 |
| 7 | A | B | C | 3.4 |

...
...

And this process is done for multiple products. All the categorical space of combinations is being explored during *n* days for different products.

The ideal forecasting will be something like predicting the next 5 days for the given categorical combination i.e catA=A, catB=B and catB=B, and it will forecast different results depending on the categorical input.

I have been looking for something to model this problem and Prophet (with its additional regressors) looks interesting but I do not know if it is the (best) approach.
I have also thought of a Bayesian regression due to I can introduce some prior knowledge on the distribution that the categorical features follow:

*y* = catA + catB + catC where *y* are the different time series as mentioned before.

What kind of model/framework/approach do you think I must follow to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple items and for a given item the category is static then you won't get much benefit from models like prophet / arima as they only fit single time series. Your best bet would be using LightGBM/XGBoost and creating lagged features of your target and moving averages as well as date features.

You could give [mlforecast](https://github.com/Nixtla/mlforecast) a shot.